# Passing vector input into MATLAB function

Tags: matlab, function, vector

I am trying to write a function in MATLAB that takes 1x3 vectors as input. My code looks something like this:

```
function myFunction=([x1, x2, x3], [y1, y2, y3], [z1, z2, z3])
```

where all inputs are numbers, and then in the body of the function I perform some calculations indexing through the numerical values in the vectors. i want the vectors to be user input, so the user will enter the vectors and their components (x1, x2, etc.) into the function argument. However, I am getting an error saying "Invalid expression. When calling a function or indexing a variable, use parentheses. Otherwise, check for mismatched delimiters." Therefore I believe I either have the syntax or something else wrong. I know MATLAB is supposed to be able to take vector input in functions, so please let me know what I am doing wrong. Thanks!

Comment: That is not how you define a function. The first line should be `function output = myFunction(x,y,z)`. Then in the function body you can recall the first element of `x`, `x1`, using `x(1)` etc. See [`function`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function.html).

Comment: My function doesn't have any output, so isn't that how you define a function without output?

Comment: Without any output you would define it as `function myFunction(x,y,z)`.

Comment: But the user is supposed to define the vectors and input each element of each vector, so how would I do that?

Comment: Then you would define the function as in my previous comment, and call the function with e.g. `myFunction([1 0 0], [0 1 0], [0 0 1]);`.

Comment: So the function needs to have an output in order for it to work?

Comment: Not necessarily, but it is probably easiest if you clearly describe in your question what you are actually trying to achieve, and why you are not able to do so.

Comment: I edited my question to reflect better what I am trying to do.

Comment: Maybe this is where the confusion is: Variables in MATLAB always contain arrays, not single values. You can have an array with a single value, `x=1`, but then `x` is still an array. If you type `myFunction([1,2,3])`, then the three values will be assigned to a single input variable of the function.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is declare your function like this:

```
function myFunction(x,y,z)
% your function code here
end
```

Then within your function you can access the individual elements of the vectors using `x(1)`, `y(2)`, etc.

To call the function, including whatever number you like, you can enter on the Matlab command window (for example),
`myFunction([1 2 3],[4 5 6],[7 8 9])` and the code in your function will be called with the `x` variable set to the vector `[1,2,3]`, the `y` variable set to `[4,5,6]` and `z` to `[7,8,9]`.  The use of commas to delineate values is optional.  If your function then accesses `y(2)` it will get the second value of the `y` vector which will be `5` - it is important to note that indexing in Matlab is 1-based so the 1st element of `x` is obtained with `x(1)`.

If you need to return values you can use:

```
function [a,b,c] = myFunction(x,y,z)
```

Then just assign the `a`, `b` or `c` in your code before the `end` statement.

See the [offical Matlab documentation](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function.html) for more info.

I would add that much of the advantage of matlab is dealing with data in a vectorised form, so if you can avoid splitting out into separate elements I would do so.  For example, if you need to add two vecors, you could do `z = [x(1)+y(1), x(2)+y(2), x(3)+y(3)]`, but much better (more readable, more maintainable, faster) is `z=x+y`.

Comment: But the idea is that the user inputs the numbers in the vectors. So this wouldn't work for my purposes?

Comment: @user12142743 Then I think you need to explain much more what you are doing, as it is not clear enough in your questions what your intention is.  Saying 'a function which takes' implies a function where values are supplied programatically, not user input.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my question so that it better reflects what I am trying to do.

Comment: @user12142743 in this example, `x` `y` and `z` can be vectors, numbers, objects, functions, files, or any other supported type of object. In MATLAB, you don't need to define variables, they just "are". The reason why sometimes MATLAB functions error with the wrong data types is because they have explicit input parsing code, e.g. `assert(~isscalar(x),'Error:X is a single number')`

Comment: @user12142743 I suspect that you might be better served with following a tutorial on matlab rather than jumping straight in.  I've edited my answer above to hopefully cover where, I think, your misconceptions lie, however if that still does not work for you then I suggest you might like to consider a tutorial instead (just google 'matlab tutorial', there are loads out there).